# Clear cache not working

Tags: phpstorm, symfony, php-5.6

I'm working with Symfony 3, PhpStorm and php interpreter 5.6.19.

When I want to open a project developed by my colleague with php interpreter 5.5.12 its not working it show me this error :

> C:\wamp64\www\workshopStatistiques\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PassConfig.php on line 66

and when I clear cache it show :

> Cannot run program "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe" (in directory "C:\wamp64\www\workshopStatistiques")

Does anyone have any idea how can I repair this error?

Comment: Try deleting the var/cache directory though I would not have expected a reference to the php executable to be in there.  In general, you should not transfer the var files from one installation to another.

Comment: Do you guys share PHPStorm's project files?  It looks like you've opened PHPStorm projected configured for your friend's environment.

Comment: @Jakub Matczak yes, exactly!so what's the solution?

Comment: @Marooweb don't do that. :) At least not all of them. Some of them are portable, but some of them - as you can see - are specific for environment.

Answer (score 0):

I delete the var folder and its working.